# Taking Partial Derivatives at a Point $(y_0,z_0)$, can I substitute the other variable in first?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Consider $F(y,z) = \int_0^{z^2} z \sin(yt) \, dt$.

Suppose I want to calculate $\partial F_z$ at the point $(0,1).$ I can do it two ways, but it seems like I get different answers. Can someone shed some light on what's wrong here?

**Method 1: Integrate and then differentiate**

$$\partial F_z = \partial F_z\frac{z}{y}(-\cos(z^2y)+1) = \frac{-\cos(yz^2)+2yz^2\sin(yz^2)+1}{y}.$$
Here I can't plug in $(0,0,1),$ since the partial derivative is not defined at points where $y=0$.

**Method 2: Substitute $y=0$ first and then take the partial derivative since I'm only interested in the partial derivative in the $z$-direction.**

$$\partial F_z (0,z) = \partial F_z \int_0^{z^2} z \sin(0 \cdot t) \, dt = 0$$

Why do I get conflicting results?

Comment: In the first method use limit $y\to 0$. You will also get $0$

Comment: @Andrei Why is it valid to use a limit when the partial derivative is not defined at that point?

Comment: As you noticed, $F(0,z)=0$. The formula you use in method 1 is valid everywhere except at $0$. It just happens that this function is continuous, and the derivative is continuous as well. But you would need to prove that

Answer (score 0):

$$
\int_0^{z^2} z \sin(yt) \, dt = \begin{cases} \quad 0 & \text{if } y=0, \\[8pt]
\dfrac{-z} y ( \cos(yz^2) -1 ) & \text{otherwise.} \end{cases}
$$
Your way of integrating is valid only when $y\ne0.$